# How to find the smallest change in voltage

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-engineering, computer-hardware

You are comparing different A/D converters that will have 3.2 V and -3.2 V as their positive and negative reference voltages, respectively. Out of the following, converter **_ can resolve the smallest change in voltage, which is approximately_**  . (m = milli and u = micro)

(A) 16-bit, 100 kHz

(B) 8-bit, 1 MHz

(C) 15-bit, 512 kHz

(D) 19-bit, 256 kHz

(E) 17-bit, 330 kHz

Comment: Are you testing us? This is not a homework completion site. Show which you think is correct **and** explain why you think that - then you may get some feedback.

Comment: Please show your current work? What help do you need?

Comment: Two words: Keithley Instruments.

Answer (score 2):

I order to solve this problem there one needs to understand the following

- ADC **range** which is the maximum and minimum ADC input. For this problem the range is 3.2V, -3.2V.
- ADC **resolution** which is the smallest distinguishable change in input. For a 12 bit converter this would be 6.4V/4096 = 0.0015625V

Below is an example for range of 3.3V based on a 12 bit converter.

[image]

Base on the above detail it should be possible to find the solution to above problem. In order to learn details I suggest checking out the following references.

**Reference**:

- [Analog to Digital Conversion, Data Acquisition and Control](http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/Volume1/E-Book/C14_ADCdataAcquisition.htm)
- [Embedded Systems - Shape The World: Microcontroller Input/Output](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-the-world-microcontroller-inputoutput)